# Why isn't this youtube shortcode working?

Tags: shortcode, youtube

```
echo do_shortcode('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZBCTc9zHtI');
```

Is merely printing

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZBCTc9zHtI"
```

out onto the page.

I know I can display the video with html with

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vZBCTc9zHtI" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but I'm trying to leverage wordpress' built-in methods. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php echo wp_oembed_get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZBCTc9zHtI'); ?>
```

For more details check this [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get).

Comment: While this shows oembed retrieval in principle, it's very important to note that it will have WP make a network request _every time_ it's called. For any practical usage the result must be **cached**. For embeds in posts the results are stored in post meta, if I remember right.

Comment: @Rarst How can you make sure this is cached?

Comment: You need to implement caching logic yourself with code if you use this in your own code, using one of WP data storage APIs (transient would be usual choice for such case).

Comment: @Rarst Do you really think implementation of caching logic will be important if the website going to have only a few videos. Personally I never felt the important of caching for such websites and for website with lots of videos, definitely going to need different approach for adding into the website!!

Comment: Count of videos is irrelevant, even one would slow page generation time significantly and unnecessarily. Please consider that you are not writing an answer for a one small site, you are writing an answer for general case of WP development.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to embed a video in the content area, WordPress does this pretty elegantly with [oembeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds). You just need to paste the URL into the editor and save the post. As long as the embeds are supported, WordPress will work its magic and format your embed.

Your call to [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) doesn't make sense.  As posted, your code is saying, "look through this youtube URL string and run the shortcodes found within it".

Answer (score 1):

```
do_shortcode()
```

Is used to printout shortcode. And you are writting URL in it. No use of this.
Try to implement

```
wp_oembed_get( $url, $args )
```

This will work for you.
So your code will

```
wp_oembed_get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZBCTc9zHtI')
```

or if you want to specify width then

```
wp_oembed_get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZBCTc9zHtI', array('width'=>400))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because using a youtube url in the content has nothing to do with shortcodes, which is why it doesn't work when you try to call `do_shortcode`, what it actually does is to envoke the oEmbed protocol which is a very different thing.

There is an oEmbed shorcode and you probably can do `do_shortcode('[oEmbed youtube.com.....]')` but as other answers pointed out, there is an explicit API for that and using the shortcode is the long way to do that.

The most important thing to keep in mind in what you are trying to do, is that oEmbed sends a request to youtube servers and waits to a reply, which means that without some caching this kind of code will slow down the page on every load.